# two seemingly identical table cells render with different widths

Tags: css

I have two tables whose columns should be the same width.  Despite both being set to width: 0.27in, column one in the first table renders as 28px wide and column one in the other at 29px.  I can't figure out why.

Here is an example

http://isispro.com/render_error/

Here's the html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Isis Pro Gynecological Case List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="print_gyn_style.css?v=1" media="screen">
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<table class="headerA pageHeader">
    <tr>
        <td class="headerLeft">
            Candidate's Name: ernst schoen-rene<br />
            Caselist Number: abog001
        </td>
        <td class="headerCenter">
            <b>List of gynecological patients (main post-residency 12 months cases)</b>
        </td>
        <td class="headerRight">July  1, 2012 - September 30, 2012<br />
            <span class="pageNum"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p></p>

<table class="headerB">
    <tr>
        <td class="centerBottom col1">#</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col2">H<br />o<br />s<br />p<br />#</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col3">P<br />a<br />t<br />#</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col4">A<br />g<br />e</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col5">G<br />r<br />a<br />v</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col6">P<br />a<br />r<br />a</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col7">Diagnosis: Preoperative or Admission (include size of ovarian cysts)</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col8">Treatment</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col9">Surgical Pathology Diagnosis (Uterine wt. in gms.)</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col10">Complications (include blood transfusions)</td>
        <td class="centerBottom col11">Days in Hosp</td>
        <td class="noBorder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="noBorder"></td>
        <td class="noBorder"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>




<h2 class="">Abdominal hysterectomy, any type</h2>
<table class="cases">

    <tr>
        <td class="col1">1</td>
        <td class="col2">A</td>
        <td class="col3">A-1</td>
        <td class="col4">12</td>
        <td class="col5">1</td>
        <td class="col6">15</td>
        <td class="col7">fdsa  fdsa</td>
        <td class="col8">f ads</td>
        <td class="col9">fd sa</td>
        <td class="col10">fdsa</td>
        <td class="col11">4</td>
        <td class="noBorder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="noBorder"></td>
        <td class="noBorder"></td>
    </tr>



</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
@page {
    margin: 2in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in;
}

body, html {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

h1,h2,h3 {
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
/*  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: -1.5in; */

}

h1 {
    font-size: 14pt;
    margin: 1pt;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin: 3 0;
}

table {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.pageBreak {
    page-break-after: always;
    height: 1px;
}

.pageHeader {
    width: 10.15in;
}

.pageNum:before {
  content: "Page " counter(page);
}

.headerLeft {
    text-align: left;
}

.headerCenter {
    text-align: center;
}

.headerRight {
    text-align: right;
}

.headerB {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 10.15in;
}
.headerB td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.headerB .centerBottom {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.headerB .leftBottom {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


.cases {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 10.15in;
}
.cases td {
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.headerB .col1,
.headerB .col2,
.headerB .col4,
.headerB .col5,
.headerB .col6 {
    width: 0.2700in;
    text-align: center;
}
.cases .col1,
.cases .col2,
.cases .col4,
.cases .col5,
.cases .col6 {
    width: 0.2700in;
    text-align: center;
}

.headerB .col3,
.cases .col3 {
    width: 0.35in;
}


.headerB .col7,
.headerB .col8,
.headerB .col9,
.headerB .col10 {
    width: 1.37in;
}
.cases .col7,
.cases .col8,
.cases .col9,
.cases .col10 {
    width: 1.44in;
}

.cases .col11,
.headerB .col11 {
    width: 0.35in;
}

.headerB .noBorder,
.cases .noBorder {
    border: none;
    width: 0.35in;
}

.headerB .col12 {
    width: 0.5in;
    border: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.headerB .col13 {
    width: 1in;
    border: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.cases .coll12 {
    width: 0.5in;
}

.cases .coll13 {
    width: 1in;
}

.headerGray {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 0.85in;
}


.headerGray .leftBottom {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


.headerGray .col1 {
    width: 0.5in;
}

.headerGray .col2 {
    width: 1in;
}

.categoryPlusOne {
    /*page-break-before: always;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's adjusting because your wider columns have different sizes between the two tables:

```
.headerB .col7,
.headerB .col8,
.headerB .col9,
.headerB .col10 {
    width: 1.37in;
}
.cases .col7,
.cases .col8,
.cases .col9,
.cases .col10 {
    width: 1.44in;
}
```

When I used Firebug to change them to match each other, the other columns lined up and matched sizes.

Also, just as an aside, you may want to sub points for pixels since it appears you're designing for print. ;)

Comment: yes, duh!  Thanks.  A lot of the reason this is using weird numbers is because the pdf converter I'm using has lots of bugs and needs coaxing to work correctly.

Comment: No worries - every day this week feels like a Monday, so I suppose a few Monday-level mistakes are sure to get through.